# Magento 1.9 (.3.1) CSS auto-reverted to an older version

Tags: magento-1.9, css

We're using a custom theme built on top of rwd theme and when I do changes to our theme's CSS files, everything is fine for next about a day or two, then those changes are auto-reverted to previous versions of the same CSS files. JS and (p)HTML files are NOT affected, only CSS. I did look if we have (we took over the store, not build it) a scss/sass/less auto-compiler and I can't find it, so this is not causing problems.

I am not an expert in Magento but I do know my way around it, but this issue is really mind-boggling. I also noticed that there's no similar issue to be found on Google ...

Does any of you have an idea what could be causing this restoration of old CSS files? There's not backup solution set, so this is out of the question.

We're not merging CSS and JS files, they are being served directly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing in the default magento build that would be reverting your css. If you are using a CDN ensure that the updated files have been cached. I would recommend checking the timestamps on the files in question.

Comment: No CDN as well (sorry for not mentioning it before). Timestamps of files in question are as I said, most show old times, the changed ones show that something overwritten them a day or two after I uploaded them to live server.

Comment: Is this your own custom theme that you built?

Comment: No, I just took over management of the store and migrated it to Hypernode.

Comment: Have you checked ftp transfer logs or bash history?

Comment: Yes, nothing strange. Hypernode/Byte support said that CSS files are most probably recompiled from LESS, so I will have to take another look into that. The only strange thing is that not all LESS files are available for all CSS, especially those that are being overwritten. Does Magento somehow sort CSS styling according to multistore codes? Files that are mostly overwritten are "design_en.css" and "design_nl.css".

Comment: I have the same problem, I also use smartwave granada template. I make some changes in a css file but after a few days it auto-reverts to the original version. How did you solve it?

Comment: @Carlos: As you can read my answer below, there was additional file that caused this. Check if the same applies to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was causing the CSS revert, template itself. I figured out that it had a CSS template file hidden under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/smartwave/granada/css/` which was called `design.phtml`. That file also dynamically loaded CSS settings from database which could be changed in admin and then it generated a copy per storeview.